# subprocess FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory when open external program in PATH

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working on a Mac and I'm trying to open an external program (Visual Studio Code) using the subprocess module in Python. The `code` binary file is in `usr/local/bin`, which is in the `PATH` variable. My code works fine when I run it on a shell using `python3.8 main.py`. However, when I run the program using IDLE, Python keeps giving me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mike/Desktop/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(['code'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'code'
```

My code is as simple as it can get:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['code'])
```

Does anyone know what's causing the problem and how I can fix it?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: To access environment variables, I think you have to add $, like '$code'in the command.

Comment: @PratikGandhi How is this related? And how should that work in Python?

Comment: are you sure IDLE is keeping the same environment variables?  i.e. what does `os.environ['PATH']` give you?

Comment: Are you able to run 'code' from terminal??, just for test, try to run subprocess.Popen(['ls'])

Answer (score 0):

If there are any extension, can you try with that while opening the file. Also we can try with providing the absolute path once.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the full path of visual studio code, instead of just the word 'code'

```
subprocess.Popen(['usr/local/code'])
```